# How can I disable a built-in microphone?

Tags: security, microphone

How can I stop a built-in microphone from working?

```
sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_intel
```

does not work.

Answer (score 2):

If using Pulseaudio, go to Pulseaudio Volume Control configuration tab:

```
pavucontrol -t 5
```

Find audio device and change setting from 'Duplex' (recording and playback) to 'Playback'

Alternatively, mute microphone input in ALSA:

```
alsamixer
```

use F6 to select correct sound device
use F4 to show capture devices
left-right arrow keys to select sub-device
use down arrow to reduce all recording levels to 0
'M' on keyboard toggles mute - {MM] when muted, [OO] unmuted

Comment: Or switch the microphone in pavucontrol (PulseAudio VolumeControl) in the Configuration tab to `Off`.